# Windows Phone 8 - App Crashing after opening Google Admob Interstitial

Tags: windows-phone-8, crash, admob, interstitial

I have integrated admob interstitial ads into my app as Google AdMob SDK sample. After initialize interstitial ad, it appear fine. Problem occures when I clicked on ad and navigate to browser then pressing device's back button to navigate back into app, app crashes every times. Result is crash with message: "The given key was not present in the dictionary."

Is there any solution to stop crashing app?

Comment: AdMon is not recommended pour windows phone. Some crash, not optimistic performance, not good ratio.. No app crash = good position in windows phone store for remember. Prefer PubCenter.

Comment: Can you show the code?

Answer (score 0):

Same here.

1. Ad loads.
2. User clicks on add
3. Press 'back' button.
4. App crashes.

Apparently AdMob is aware of the issue (its their bug) but  I dont think they are in any rush to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and solve using following code.
This is a workaround.just add given code in app.xml.cs file of your solution.

```
 private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        String ex = e.ExceptionObject.ToString().ToLower();

        if (ex.Contains("system.collections.generic.keynotfoundexception"))
        {
            //Caused by Google fullscreen ads
            e.Handled = true;
        }
         else if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
            Debugger.Break();
        }

    }
```